# Popup facility location

Tags: reference-request, facility-location

I was searching through articles for popup facility location and could not find anything devoted to it. If anyone has come across it, can someone guide me to some papers?

Comment: Would you see [this](https://dspace.library.uu.nl/bitstream/1874/317305/2/Rogier%2520Knoops%2520-%2520Thesis%2520May%25202015.pdf) link?

Comment: @A.Omidi I am looking for a more mathematical optimization related paper